# api-platform filter out the soft deleted items

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have setup the soft delete for my Store entity by using [softdelete](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md).

This is my filter setup in the `doctrine.yml`:

```yaml
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

So when I hit e.g. the URL `/stores` only the active stores are returned, but if I change the config to `enabled: false` it will give me all the results including deleted items, which is correct.

Now what I want to achieve is pass a query parameter from front-end like `/stores?deleted=1` and then I want to get all the data, if no `deleted=1` found only the active items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create an event listener that uses the `Request` object and Doctrine's entity manager, and disables this filter? Something like this:

```php
class FilterListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            RequestEvent::class => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ($request->query->getBoolean('deleted')) {
            $this->entityManager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect this would work thanks, anyway got solved by adding a custom `SoftDeleteableFilter`

Comment: get an error `Filter 'soft-deleteable' is not enabled.` any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that. Have you checked whether it is globally enabled in `doctrine.yaml` before running your request?

Comment: I think it's there as attached image

Comment: This is not working for me. I have checked and the method is executed but in the query it still adds `(p0_.deleted_at IS NULL) ` and deleted records are not returned.  
Also I had to remove `$event->isMasterRequest()` else the code below was not executed for API Collection request.

Answer (score 0):

Since answer from @nico-haase didn't work for me, I am posting similar solution that works for me using Symfony 5.3 and Api Plarform 2.6:

```php
class FilterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['modifyFilters', EventPriorities::PRE_READ],
        ];
    }

    public function modifyFilters(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        // show deleted entities in case deleted param is provided
        if ($request->query->getBoolean('deleted')) {
            $this->entityManager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
        }
    }
}
```